# jQuery Selecting <a> tags with an attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a number of anchor tags with data attributes:

```
<a data-country="CA" data-symbol="RY" href="#">...
<a data-country="CA" data-symbol="DD" href="#">...
<a data-country="CA" data-symbol="FF" href="#">...
```

I need to select them, so that when they click I cancel the click and get the data values:

Here's what I tried, but both the selector and the getting of the data-fields doesn't work.

```
$("a[data-symbol]").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  doSomething($(this).data("symbol"), $(this).data("country"));
});
```

Comment: What's `doSomething`? And you need to close your anchor tags. Your general plan seems fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/CWYkD/

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/w4QpC/

Comment: You need to close your anchor tags (if you haven't done so in your real code).

Comment: Actually it still works even with the messed up HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/w4QpC/1/ (using Chrome)

Comment: [jquery has attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

Comment: Is your Javascript in a script element that appears after the anchors, or wrapped by a document ready handler? @baltov - the OP is already using that selector...

Comment: Are the anchors added to the page later via javascript?

Comment: Syntax: jQuery.data( element, key ), you should use $(this).attr("data-symbol"), etc. ?

Comment: @jacouh - the OP's syntax for `.data()` is correct for retrieving element `data-` attribute values.

Comment: @nnnnnn, I should study more jQuery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could remove doSomething() and seperate the data attributes:

```
$("a[data-symbol]").click(function(e) {
    var elm, data1, data2;
    e.preventDefault();
    elm = $(this);
    data1 = elm.data("symbol");
    data2 = elm.data("country");
    console.log(data1,data2)
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xs5Fa/1/)

And also close the anchor tags.

Comment: I don't understand what's different about this that it would work when the code in the question didn't.

Comment: I removed the doSomething function and separated the data attribute calls. Also put $(this) into a variable and included a console.log to show the result.

Comment: Yes, I can see _what_ you changed. My question is _why_ do the changes you made fix the problem? Why wouldn't the original have worked? (Assuming that `doSomething()` was actually defined somewhere, but presumably the OP wants to do something with the values other than just log them...)

Comment: You should declare var elm, data1, data2; in the function to not pollute the js global variables space.

Comment: The original wasn't working because of the function. The shorter approach for getting the data attributes helps and the console log is just an example that could be adapted. Thanks all.